# Create .csv with data from text and empty lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm looking for a script to generate a .csv from a text file. While the text file contains only one value per line I need to add empty values with a specific length:

Source text file

```
4711
3821
1253423
234332
```

Desired output .csv file:

- Column 1: Length of 5
- Column 2: Length of 10
- Column 3: Data from text
- Column 4: Length of 3

Source text file

```
     ;          ;4711;   ;
     ;          ;3821;   ;
     ;          ;1253423;   ;
     ;          ;234332;   ;
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{NF=4;$3=$1;$1="";printf("%5s;%10s;%s;%3s;\n",$1,$2,$3,$4)}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf "%5s;%10s;%s;%3s;\n","","",$1,""}' file

     ;          ;4711;   ;
     ;          ;3821;   ;
     ;          ;1253423;   ;
     ;          ;234332;   ;
```